# Class array to view

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have the following question.
In one of my classes i use in the contruct $this->view->title = $titlearray; 
This works in the add.php

Now i want to do the same thing in the same class in an another method

```
public function addAction() {
$this->view->errors = $errorarray;
}
```

In the add.php i want to display the array

```
$errors = $this->errors;
foreach ($errors as $value) {echo $value;}
```

But this doesnt work.
Someone an idea?

```
class Controller_PagesController {

private $view;

public function __construct( ){
    $this->view = new View();
    $this->view->title = 'title example';
}

public function addAction(){
    $this->view->errors = array(1=>'required',2=>'minlenght');    
}
```

^^^^^^^Construct works and addAction not in the add.php

add.php example

```
$title = $this->title; //string
$errors = $this->erors; //array
echo $title; //works
foreach ($errors as $value) {print_r($value);} //doesnt work
```

Comment: $this only has meaning when you are in a class context... are you trying to use $this outside of a class?

Comment: where are you getting the $errorArray variable from ... it doesn't appear to be in the scope of the addAction method

Comment: See example class above, thanks

Comment: `$this->erors` <- typo ?

Comment: @CORRUPT changed, doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
public function addAction() {
    $this->view->errors = $errorarray;
}
```

and at your add.php directly use

```
foreach ($errors as $value) {print_r($value);}
```

and print the data $errors if you want to check
and have you tried with

```
public function addAction(){
    $this->view->errors['errors'] = array(1=>'required',2=>'minlenght');    
}
```

and in view print $errors

Comment: Only the the __construct gives them throught and not the variables in the addAction.